# How to reduce time to load the markers on the ios google mapview?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm using google maps sdk in ios application, where I'm adding an array of markers on the mapview.
The markers to be added to the mapview are too many in count, so its blocking the UI while loading the markers onto the map.
Is there any other way to add the markers to the map which wont block the UI ?
This is how I'm adding the markers to the mapview.

```
GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker.position = location;
marker.icon = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imageName ofType:@"png"]];
marker.title = title;
marker.animated = animated;
marker.tappable = tappable;
marker.map = _mapView;
```

The above set of code is iterated using a for loop and the markers were created and added to the map.

Thanks.

Comment: Say for example 1000 markers were added at a stretch in the google maps.

Comment: the mapview isn't 'thread safe' so while the icon could be loaded on the bg thread, the marker can't be added there

Answer (score 1):

Put the whole setup of the series of the place markers (in my case I do it in a for loop) in another thread then the block will let the view goes first, put the view setup including the for loop and show each marker on the map back to the main thread. hope this help =]

Version 1

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED.value), 0)) {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            for markers {
            let placeMarker = PlaceMarker()
                placeMarker.map = self.mapView
            }
        }
    }
```

Version 2, I found this method works on my iPhone but crash on simulator

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED.value), 0)) {
        for markers {
            let placeMarker = PlaceMarker()
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

                placeMarker.map = self.mapView
            }
        }
    }
```